# User Defined Build Settings in Test Targets?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, build-settings, ifndef

i have the following code in my unit tests:

```
#ifndef SERVER_TEST
    NSLog(@"\n\n!!!--- YOU ARE RUNNING TESTS IN STUB MODE ---!!!\n\n!!!--- Server Responses will be stubbed ---!!!\n\n");
#else
    NSLog(@"\n\n!!!--- YOU ARE RUNNING TESTS IN LIVE MODE ---!!!\n\n!!!--- Server Responses will be live ---!!!\n\n");
#endif
```

SERVER_TEST is defined under Build Settings in my Test target's User Defined Settings.

When I run my tests, #ifndef SERVER_TEST always returns True.  Any ideas why?

Thanks?

Comment: Have you tried [using a custom configuration](http://www.innovaptor.com/blog/2013/09/02/xcode-preprocessor-macros-for-test-code.html)?

Comment: No, I haven't.  What would be the advantage of using a custom config, compared to Grzegorz's answer?

Comment: If you wanted to use the same define in your app code for conditionally compiling in, say, custom logging during test runs, a custom config is best of managing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep this flag as Preprocessor macro instead of User Defined Settings.

Comment: That worked! Is there any reason why this works, instead of a User Defined Setting?

Comment: User Defined Settings are more for keeping variable values - you can read them from code by $(VARIABLE NAME). #ifdef is preprocessor macro so it should be used. You can combine them both, and define variable value in UserDefinedSettings and use them in preprocessor macro as $(VARIABLE_FROM_USER_DEFINES). User defined settings are not translated into preprocessor macro automatically, until you define them in macro section.